# useState() is returning undefined and I don't know why

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Can anyone tell me why the console.log statement is returning `undefined`. I realise this would be undefined if it were getting data from an API, but the data is positioned above it?

```
const Slider = () => {
  const movies = {
    1: {
      title: "first title",
      image: "first image",
      url: "first url"
    },
    2: {
      title: "second title",
      image: "second image",
      url: "second url"
    },
    3: {
      title: "third title",
      image: "third image",
      url: "third url"
    },
    4: {
      title: "third title",
      image: "thirs image",
      url: "third url"
    }
  }

  const [ currentMovie, setMovie ] = useState(movies[0])
  const [ active, setActive ] = useState(0)
  console.log(currentMovie)
}
```

Comment: The `movies` you have defined is an Object, not an Array. And, if you want to select attribute in Object via string, you can use `movies['1']`

Comment: Your movies object doesn't have a key `0`.

Comment: Jesus I'm dumb, thanks a lot :)

Comment: @unicorn_surprise It's okay. Happens to the best of us.:D

Answer (score 3):

here you are using a javascript object, not an array, and there is no key for 0.
So, indeed, the result for movie[0] is undefined